# Unity - IOS application.openUrl didn't work after build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mobile

I need help, i use `application.OpenUrl` for link in my app, (c# code), in unity, everythings work perfectly, but when i build it on my iphone, or ipad, the link didn't work..

Sorry for my english.
Here is the code :

```
 public void onClick(Button btn)
{
    string nombtn = btn.name;

    if (infosNomUrl.ContainsKey(nombtn)) {
        url = infosNomUrl[nombtn];

        Application.OpenURL(url);
    }

}
```

on iOS only the last link work.
But on Unity preview all links are working, is there a compatibility problem of OpenURL function on iOS ?
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: show the complete line of code that doesn't work

Comment: Any errors in XCode console?

Comment: (Just a guess) Also make sure you have no spaces in the URL itself, if you do ios will fail on this call and you will have to Escape the url,

Comment: Can you provide a list with the links you are trying to use?